# Odd / strange directory 6ad59dd7287df814106109 on my Win 7 / Data drive

Tags: windows-7, files

On my Win 7 data drive I find a directory which does not mean anything to me: 6ad59dd7287df814106109, which contains subfolders such as 1024, 1025, 1026 ...

I need administrative rights to get into that directory. I have no idea where this directory comes from, I cannot delete it (files are still used by other program).

Has somebody an idea how I can delete it or find the source of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This almost certainly comes from a large Windows update -- Service Pack, .Net etc.  Take ownership of the directory, grant yourself full control and delete away.  Certain updates will determine the local disk containing the most free space and extract to the root automatically.

http://www.winxptutor.com/randomfolders.htm